# How do you trigger sharding tables in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

How do you shard multiple tables of the same format in BigQuery?

Answer (score 1):

I think the only native way is to split tables by date, in the form:

```
table_name_YYYYMMDD
```

Then you can query that entire collection of tables via TABLE_DATE_RANGE.

If you manually shard on some other basis, you can perform a union query simply by listing the tables separated by commas:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  table1, table2
```